# Insert Value from two data frame on some condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have two dataframe, first one is file and second one is mapfile.
want to change the value of carrier(file) based on the col of carrie(mapfile).
Please help me out from this problem. Attached snap for reference.

```
for i in file['Carrier']:
    if i in mapfile['Carrier']:
        print("Found")
        file['Sanitized Carrier Name']= mapfile[i+1]

file.to_excel("file.xlsx")
```

file(dataframe1)[Input data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgOvU.png)
mapfile(dataframe2)[Reference Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUW40.png)

Comment: `file.merge(mapfile.rename(columns={'col A': 'Carrier', 'col B': 'Port', 'Carrier': 'Sanitized Carrier'}, how='left')`